# How to split a string by ':' but ignoring '\:' in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to split a string for example

**Input:**

`username:password\:partofpassword`

when I split it by ':' it should return 2 strings:

**Output:**

`username`

`password:partofpassword`

So basically it should understand that any ':' after '\' is to be ignored while splitting the string.

Comment: I don't find any `'\' ` in `"username:password:partofpassword"`, what is your actual requirement?

Comment: What if the input is `username:password\\:partofpassword` where ``\`` escaped another ``\``? The lookbehind approach won't work then. [Look, here, both 2 colons should get matched, shouldn't they?](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%3a&i=username%3apassword%5c%5c%3apartofpassword)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Split(myString, @"(?<!\\):")
```

The `(?<!\)` is a negative lookbehind.

Comment: It works like a charm as far as ignoring the ':' after '\' is concerned. Couple of things though: 1) I am not able to declare a string like "username:password\:partofpassword" it says unrecognized escape sequence. So I had to declare it as: "username:password\\:partofpassword". 2) after splitting, it returned two string: string[0] - "username", string[1]- "password\\:partofpassword" string[1] should be "password:partofpassword".

Comment: @AshishAgrawal your requirements are very strange. I'd probably keep the `\\:` and use `Regex.Unescape("password\\:partofpassword")`

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, why can't you declare your string as @"username:password\:partofpassword"? This will free you from using \\:

Comment: @JuryGolubev yes I was able to figure that out. I did that and it now works fine. Thanks :)